# a tikzpicture on pages without chapter and index

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, page-numbering

I would get the result of the output below

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
papersize={19.7cm,27cm},
centering,
textwidth=380pt,
textheight=650pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title of chapter}
\section{and section}
Bla bla bla. In this page the pagestyle would be empty.
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[lightgray] (-90pt,1cm) rectangle (0pt,2.5cm); %riquadro ad inizio pagina
    \draw[gray] (-90pt,1cm)--(470pt,1cm);   %linea sotto riquadro ad inizio pagina
    \fill[lightgray] ({\textwidth/2-30pt},-23.45cm) rectangle ({\textwidth/2+30pt},-24.45cm);   %riquadro per la pagina
    \draw[gray] (-90pt,-23.45cm)--(470pt,-23.45cm); %linea di fondo pagina
    \node at (0,1.25cm) [left]{\sffamily\chaptername\ \thechapter};
    \node at (0,1.25cm) [right]{\slshape\sffamily\leftmark};
    \node at (380pt,1.25cm) [left] {\slshape\sffamily author};
    \node at ({\textwidth/2},-23.9cm) {\bfseries\sffamily\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}

Here there is some text (here the number of the page is even);

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[lightgray] (380pt,1cm) rectangle (470pt,2.5cm);   %riquadro (destro) ad inizio pagina
    \draw[gray] (-90pt,1cm)--(470pt,1cm);   %linea sotto riquadro ad inizio pagina
    \fill[lightgray] ({\textwidth/2-30pt},-23.45cm) rectangle ({\textwidth/2+30pt},-24.45cm);   %riquadro per la pagina
    \draw[gray] (-90pt,-23.45cm)--(470pt,-23.45cm); %linea di fondo-pagina
    \node at (380pt,1.25cm) [right]{\sffamily\chaptername\ \thechapter};
    \node at (380pt,1.25cm) [left]{\slshape\sffamily\leftmark};
    \node at (0pt,1.25cm) [right]{\slshape\sffamily\rightmark};
    \node at ({\textwidth/2},-23.95cm) {\bfseries\sffamily\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}

And here there is some text too (here the number of the page is odd).
\end{document}
```

but on every page of the document. I already notice that there is a discussion about my question, but there I cannot obtain sufficient information on the use of `everypage` package, or something that put me on the right track to solve this problem.

Comment: the `background` package sounds like it would be pretty useful here

Comment: Are you sure this should go on *every* page, even for special pages such as the first page of a chapter, or pages that are usually left blank?

Comment: No: I mean to put the two pictures above on every page that does not contain index or chapters. I will take a look to the `background` package documentation in order to realise how avoid these special pages

Comment: have you tried to solve it with `scrpage2`

Comment: @Lorenzo I don't think `background` is the more useful option here; see the reasons in my answer below. By the way, I would suggest you to change the title of your question since, in its present form, it is misleading (you don't really want the formatting on *every* page).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possibility, using the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package to define a page style with the specifications required:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
papersize={19.7cm,27cm},
centering,
textwidth=380pt,
textheight=650pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text automatically

\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+18pt\relax}

\setlength\headheight{13.6pt}
\fancyhfoffset[L,R]{\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+18pt\relax}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[LE]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\fill[lightgray] (0,-4pt) rectangle (\mylen,\headheight+1in);
\node[anchor=east,font=\sffamily] at (\mylen,0) {\strut\chaptername~\thechapter};
\node[anchor=west,font=\slshape\sffamily] at (\mylen,0) {\strut\leftmark};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fancyhead[RE]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\fill[lightgray] (0,-4pt) rectangle (\mylen,\headheight+1in);
\node[anchor=east,font=\slshape\sffamily] at (-90pt,0) {\strut Author};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fancyhead[RO]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\fill[lightgray] (-\mylen,-4pt) rectangle (0,\headheight+1in);
\node[anchor=east,font=\slshape\sffamily] at (-\mylen,0) {\strut\leftmark};
\node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily] at (-\mylen,0) {\strut\chaptername~\thechapter};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fancyhead[LO]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[anchor=west,font=\slshape\sffamily] at (\mylen,0) {\rightmark};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fancyfoot[C]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\fill[lightgray] (-30pt,0) rectangle (30pt,-30pt);
\node[anchor=center,font=\bfseries\sffamily] at (0,-15pt) {\thepage};
\draw (-\textwidth,0) -- (\textwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title of chapter}
\section{Title of a Section}
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some zoomed images: first, the header for an even page:

[image]

the header for an even page:

[image]

finally, a footer:

[image]

The use of the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package in this particular situation might not be the best approach since there are many pages (e.g., first page of each chapter, empty pages produced by internal `\cleardoublepage` commands) which shouldn't receive the style and doing this with `background` might require more effort than the present approach.